# How can I activate a IFTTT recipe when a Philips Hue movement sensor gets triggered?

Tags: zigbee, smart-plugs, philips-hue, ifttt

I have a Philips Hue movement sensor who's job it is to shut the light on. In addition to a hue light bulb I have a lava lamp that's currently plugged into a IFTTT compatible WLAN smart sockets.

Unfortunately, the default Philips Hue app doesn't seem to allow me to tell the movement sensor to activate an IFTTT recipe, is there a way I still get the IFTTT compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a home automation server such as:

- [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io)
- [OpenHAB](https://www.openhab.org)

Both of these should be able to do it, I haven't got any Phillips hue sensors so I can't help too much however there is a good post [here](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/tutorial-adding-hue-motion-sensor-lux-temp-and-motion/5532)

Hope that helps